# How to take screen shot in Android 5.0 or sdk >21

Tags: android

As you know, if device rooted, you can take a screen shot with code

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

But with SDK>21 (5.0 or higher ) It's not support this function.
So, I wanna know how to way screen shot with Android 5.0 or higher
from service (another application).

I seen about MediaProjectionManager, but it needs run onActivityResult for received result, but in the service, it can't active.

Answer (score 0):

This one will for you:
declare this globally in your class file-

private File imageFile;
private void takeScreenshot() {

```
    try {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"\\/pic";            View v1 = FirstScreenActivity.mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: With this method , You need get root View.
But, I want to take a shot from serivce .
Do you know another method ?

Answer (score 0):

First add an activity object in your Activity class like this-

```
public class FirstScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static Activity mActivity;
private File imageFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity=this;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();}
```

then use static mActivity in your non-activity class file like this with code above in previous answer:

```
View v1 = FirstScreenActivity.mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Comment: I know but you don't understand my question, I want to capture screen of other application.

Comment: Oh if that is the case, however it is actually security risk but yes you can do that.

Comment: for this, here is the trick...you can use a reciever ...specify it in your manifest file, and then use the specific event(many events are already defined in android like when screen is unlocked, a new sms received, sent, phone is booted) your specified receiver will have code in it for taking screenshot and will work on specific events that are in receiver. ONLY LIMITATION IS THAT you can use your receiver only at  THOSE PREDEFINED events. If this will work out for you. I will share the the code that i wrote 2 months back..:)

Comment: Ok, many thanks you.
If you have code in this funtion, please send it for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the receiver that is to be specified in your manifest file-

```
<receiver android:name=".reciever.EventReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

like these action you can choose other action also.
**NOTE:** don't forget to add permissions for the actions that you will use in your receiver.
This is the receiver class where you will write your code (in this case taking screenshots)-

```
public class EventReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
private File imageFile;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext=context;
    takeScreenshot();
//you can execute some of your other code also

}
private void takeScreenshot() {
    try {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"\\/pic";
        View v1 = FirstScreenActivity.mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Use this and the onReceive() of your receiver class will get executed on specific event action that you specified in your manifest.